# underscorejs - what is the difference between extendOwn vs extend?

Tags: underscore.js, extend

While going through [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org)'s list of methods, I couldn't help but notice a method which I don't remember being there before: [extendOwn](http://underscorejs.org/#extendOwn)

The [documentation for this method](http://underscorejs.org/#extendOwn) says the following:

> **extendOwn** _.extendOwn(destination, *sources) *Alias*: **assign**
>
> Like extend, but only copies *own* properties over to the destination object.

I understand how [*.extend()*](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) is used and what it does... but for the life of me I cannot understand how it differs from [.extendOwn()](http://underscorejs.org/#extendOwn).

I tried using [*.extend()*](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) and then [.extendOwn()](http://underscorejs.org/#extendOwn) to extend a few objects just to see if maybe there was something obvious that would happen - but they seem to both produce the same result.

```
var a = {
    foo: false
};

var b = {
    bar: true
};

// This will produce { foo: false, bar: true }; ..just like _.extend() would =\
_.extendOwn( a, b );
```

Any insight into this mystery would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have not - that's a good idea though thanks

Comment: heh, so i just read the source.   The funny thing is that it boils down to using _.keys vs _.allKeys - which in turn is different one uses nativeKeys and  the following :     for (var key in obj) if (_.has(obj, key)) keys.push(key);
where the other does not.  dunno - seems still a bit of a mystery to  me why extendOwn is even necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So for anyone wondering, a good place to find the answer is here:  https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/search?q=extendOwn&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

**Update**

For anyone interested, the answer is that `extendOwn` is synonymous with [`Object.assign`](http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/object-assign.html) with the implementation being a tiny bit different. Underscorejs simply is adding an alternative to it. Rather than overriding `assign` with a new implementation into Underscorejs and calling it `_.assign`, they are calling it `_.extendOwn` (with `_.assign` being an alias to `_.extendOwn`).

The reason for this naming convention is understandable, but imho a bit confusing. You see, `Object.assign` is ES6's official name for the method/logic we know as "extend" (as called by tools such as jQuery and Underscore).

[The decision by the Underscore team](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/2070#issuecomment-75266857) was that they decided on calling the primary/parent method `extendOwn` to adhere to their own internal standards. Naming the primary method `_.assign` would be (to the Underscore's team) counter intuitive as to them, it confuses what "extend" does. By calling it `extendOwn`, they are saying that this method does the same thing as "extend" but is based on the ES6's implementation of this functionality known as "assign".

Essentially - what they had here was a paradox, and they needed to make a decision.  Either they stick with the convention we know as "extend" or they allow "assign" - which would just conflict with that original name (which might also begin to cause people to question why they would still call the other method "extend" rather than `assignSomethinghere` instead).

Long story short - `extendOwn` is the Underscore version of ES6's `Object.assign`.  They just named it `extendOwn` to keep it in alignment with and the same naming convention, which is named extend.

Comment: I'd guess that [`hasOwnProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) might make good reading right about now.

Comment: The `_.has` call inside the `in` loop that you mentioned in your comment is probably just an alias for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`. `extendOwn` property doesn't walk up the prototype but `extend` does; there won't be any difference if you're just using simple objects (i.e. `o = { ... }`).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You've given an account of the history of why things are named as they are, but haven't explained the difference in functionality between the two methods.

Comment: re-read it again.   the articles linked in the accepted answer (and in the comment above by @muistooshort ) do the justice of actually explaining the differences of functionality question

Answer (score 12):

"Own properties" is a technical term in JS. An object's own properties are ones that it didn't inherit.

Here's a short snippet that exposes the different behavior of `extend` and `extendOwn`:

```js
// lines have length
line = { length: 4 }

// planes have width and inherit length
plane = Object.create(line)
plane.width = 5
plane.length  // 4

// making a cube object, using extend
cube = _.extend({ height: 6 }, plane)
cube.length  // 4

// making a cube object, using extendOwn
notACube = _.extendOwn({ height: 6 }, plane)
notACube.length  // undefined
```

As you can see, `extendOwn` only copied properties that were defined directly on the source, whereas `extend` also copied the ones defined along its prototype chain. Also note the symmetry with `_.has`:

```js
_.has(plane, 'width')   // true
_.has(plane, 'length')  // false
```

Comment: This answer is helpful. The Underscore documentation is really shitty at explaining this.